# Django: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I have an app called `map`. Within `map`, I have the following models being specificed:

```
class Checkin(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()

class Pin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place_id = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    checkins = models.ForeignKey(Checkin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["name", "latitude", "longitude"]
```

The migrations work fine. However, when I try to access the class Pin via the admin panel, I get this error message:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column map_pin.checkins_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...r_id", "map_pin"."place_id", "map_pin"."address", "map_pin"....
```

If I try to access the class Pin via `Pin.objects.all()` I also receive the same error.

Comment: Why you use only a datefield model as foreign key? if you want to include the **Checkin** you can use it as a abstract class, and inherit it on model **Pin** or you can use these attributes [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

Comment: You say the migrations work fine, but it sounds as though they haven't properly created the column for `checkins`. Show us what the migration files contain?

Comment: I realized what the issue was. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71880433/django-how-to-keep-code-and-database-synced-when-deploying-on-heroku